# why mergeSort faster than insertion in java

Tags: java, mergesort, insertion

I wrote a code in java using int insertion and int mergeSort. also
String insertion and String mergeSort. **my question is why mergeSort always faster?**

Comment: [Big O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Comment: Because it does less work.  See Wikipedia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because InsertionSort has time complexity O(n^2) while MergeSort has time complexity O(nlogn).

[Have a look here](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/) for a simple comparison of all the sorting algorithms. You can read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [here](http://web.mit.edu/16.070/www/lecture/big_o.pdf) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950471/understanding-big-o-logn-nlogn-nlogn2-for-calculating-complexities-in).

As a simple example, if you have 100 elements to sort, InsertionSort will do 100^2 = 10 000 operations to sort it, while MergeSort will do it with 100*log(100) = 100*2 = 200 operations, making it 50 times faster.

This becomes very important for large sets of data. When sorting an array of 1 000 000 objects, InsertionSort will perform 1 000 000 000 000 operations while MergeSort will only perform 6 000 000, making it 166 666 times faster.

In the above case, assuming you are using a computer that can do 1 billion operations per second, it would take InsertionSort 17 minutes to sort them, while MergeSort will do it in 6 milliseconds.

Do note that the above figures and time complexities apply on an average case.

Comment: that's not really an answer!

Comment: Looks like a proper answer to me.